# How can I capture the Array object returned by an api call through HTTP GET?

Tags: javascript, http, get, protractor

The API call
https://myhost.net/api/get_global_search_result/methods/test 
returns an Array object. I am trying to hold it in an Array object in order to read the attributes and values in it.

```
var queryResult = [];  
queryResult = browser.get('https://myhost.net/api/get_global_search_result/methods/test/');
console.log('result length: ' + queryResult.length);
```

This is what I see on my console:

```
result length: undefined
```

If I load the above specified URL directly in a browser instance, it shows the Array with its contents.

What is the better way of capturing the array object returned by this call?

Comment: What is `browser`? I would be very surprised if `browser.get` was a function which made a synchronous HTTP request (since they are deprecated) and then parsed the result as JSON and then returned that.

Comment: browser is a Selenium Webdriver instance.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the API documentation? I seem to recall there being a couple of different Selenium Webdriver libraries available for JS.

Comment: It is a custom API for an internal application. It is a Angular JS and Node JS application.

Comment: See the context of my comment. I was talking about the API for the JS library you are using to access Selenium Webdriver, not for the web server you are trying to access with it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using JQuery ajax request.
it would be some thing like   :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testbutton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9200/xyz/xyz/xfSJlRT7RtWwdQDPwkIMWg',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
             
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
             error: function() {
               
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: how do I add JQuery in Protractor code? Do I need to import any other module to support JQuery?

Comment: yes you need to add jQuery library to use this code.